# Getting Error "Failed to load resource: The server responded with a status of 404()" when embedding Google Maps or Calender

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, embed

I am getting an error "Failed to load resource
: the server responded with a status of 404()" when embedding google maps or google calendar. Disabling those solves the problem. But I want to add maps and calendar to my website.

[Here's a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r78Ab.jpg)

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/1/embed?title=Upcoming%20Weekly%20and%20Monthly%20Events&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=bsv4j120anumjsl487lc6qoe0g%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=Asia%2FCalcutta" style="border-width:0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

This error occurs when you are signed into Chrome. I do not see the error in other browsers, in an incognito window, or in a guest window.

When signed into Chrome, I see the error on any page with a Google Embed (Maps or Calendar) similar to the above code.

Comment: Post the code you're using to embed them.

Comment: Added code sample. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue, even when visiting the page that you can get the embed code from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start which leads me to believe this is a Google issue that they haven't put an effort into fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened for me when attempting to embed a Google Map / Calendar that was generated *while signed into a Google / Gmail account*. The error is thrown because Google is looking for a view of Maps / Calendar that was private to your account view (i.e. it's looking for a private resource, tied to your Google account). If you sign out of your personal account, then attempt to generate and embed a public Google Map / Calendar, you should not receive this error in the Chrome console.

Comment: I tried generating the embed code from an incognito window so i am totally logged-out.  When I put the new embed code in my page, i am still getting a 404 error.  The error is slightly different. I regenerated the code again, but this time in a normal window just logged-out as you said. That did the trick for me.  Now no more error.  Just thought i would add that generating the code from an incognito windows is still going to give you problems.

Comment: Actually, what i discovered is that as long as i am logged-out, i do not see that error message.  After I login, I see the 404 error message again.  Pretty weird.